# Почему пишут "вяленые на солнце"?

Tags: грамматика, орфография

На Google Books для этого выражения [столько же употреблений](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5) с одной Н (*вяленые*), сколько с двумя (*вяленные*). Моё мнение что должно быть две Н, потому что есть зависимое выражение *на солнце* и это причастие *вялить*. Исользование одной Н -- это недосмотр редакторов, или есть объяснение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ВялеНая рыба - качество, признак, свойство продукта. Это отглагольное прилагательное. Одна Н.
ВялеННая нами рыба - признак по действию. Это причастие. Две НН.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Моё мнение что должно быть две Н, потому что есть зависимое выражение на
> солнце и это причастие вялить."*

Ваше мнение вполне соответствует действующему в настоящее время правилу. Но... Думаю, что к использованию в ряде текстов в написании этого причастия  одного ***н*** вместо *положенных* двух могло в какой-то мере подтолкнуть следующее.

Неоднократно писалось, что ориентация на имеющееся правило лингвистически ненадёжна, что не всякие заимствованные слова с уверенностью диагностируют причастие, что конструкции с "несомненными причастиями" *(повозки, гружённые рабочими; крыша, крашенная малярами; волосы, стриженные парикмахером; кофта, вязанная бабушкой)* искусственны и встречаются редко...

При работе над усовершенствованием орфографического свода, начавшейся в 1990-х годах, была предпринята попытка изменить это правило. Предлагалось **практически** все формы, образованные от глаголов несовершенного вида (в том числе и ***вяленый***), писать с одним ***н*** -- и при употреблении их с зависимыми словами, и при  употреблении их без зависимых слов, напр.: *гружёные дровами повозки* и *гружёная баржа; жареная на масле картошка* и *жареная картошка…*

Текст правила, реализующего такое решение, был выработан Орфографической комиссией и получил, как пишет Н.А. Еськова, много положительных оценок. Но на последнем этапе работы комиссии был отвергнут в связи с установкой не вносить изменения в утвердившиеся в практике написания.

(По материалам книги "Лингвистические основы кодификации русской орфографии". --  М., 2009)

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли можно назвать совершенствованием упрощение орфографического свода, вызванное непониманием отдельных правил широкими народными массами. Мы не можем отличить причастие от прилагательного? Тогда давайте их вовсе на различать.

С этой орфограммой связано и написание НЕ: некошеные (заросшие травой)  - еще не кошенные (их еще не косили) луга. Получим: еще некошеные луга. А как же "еще не написанная книга"? Давайте тоже писать НЕ слитно. Потом перестанем различать причастия и прилагательные вовсе, будем их называть прилагательными с разными суффиксами. Как вам такая картина? Зато грамотность населения повысится.

И теперь о "вяленой/вяленной на солнце рыбе". Форма "вяленный" практически не встречается в текстах, например:

"Юкола бывает двух сортов: белая, только вяленая на солнце, и коричневая, которую после вяления коптят в специальных шалашах (С. В. Обручев). "Наработавшись за день, похлебали поземины или вяленухи (поземина - вяленая пластинами (без костей) рыба; вяленуха ― вяленое мясо (П. П. Бажов).

Итак, никто  не пишет "вяленная рыба" даже при наличии зависимых слов (возможно, интуитивно), потому что вяленый - это прилагательное, обозначающее качество. Рыба бывает свежая, соленая, копченая и вяленая (вялить - сушить на солнце, на открытом воздухе). "Вяленая на солнце" -  только уточнение, качества не изменяющее. Схема образования: вялить - вяленый - вяленый (на солнце).

Частное решение? Значит, правилами НУЖНО УЗАКОНИТЬ ДВА РЕШЕНИЯ - формальное и смысловое (авторское), но не отменять это правило вовсе, как это предлагалось сделать.

Comment: >> Форма "вяленный" практически не встречается в текстах

Вот те раз... Ну и аргумент.

>> Итак, никто не пишет "вяленная рыба" даже при наличии зависимых слов (возможно, интуитивно), потому что вяленый - это прилагательное, обозначающее качество.

Если заменить в вашей фразе "вялен(н)ую" на "жарен(н)ую", фраза останется такой же (не)верной?
Чем здесь "вялен(н)ый" отличается от "жерен(н)ого"?

Comment: а тем, что она сушеная, а не сушенная.

Comment: Дорогие друзья, мне только хотелось рассказать вам, что  правило о влиянии зависимых слов является  формальным, удобным для применения (особенно в школе), но с ограниченными возможностями. Русская орфография имеет семантическую и грамматическую природу, поэтому прилагательное (Н) обозначает постоянное качество, а причастие (НН)  обозначает  действие, протекающее во времени. И в частных случаях автор может ориентироваться на понимание смысла слова, не следуя общему правилу.  Пары "сушеный - сушенный" хороши для школьных упражнений, но в художественных текстах разные бывают ситуации.

Comment: Поэтому школьники должны писать "вяленная на солнце рыба", а классические тексты исправлять не стоит.

Comment: http://www.tepka.ru/pravila_russkogo/20.html

Comment:  Vera, читайте внимательнее! "Предлагалось практически все формы, образованные от глаголов несовершенного вида (в том числе и вяленый), писать с одним н…" НЕСОВЕРШЕННОГО!
.....
Vera: "А как же "еще не написанная книга"? Давайте тоже писать НЕ слитно". 
С какой стати? Глагол "написать" -- СОВЕРШЕННОГО вида. И к тому же: почему СЛИТНО?
.....
И здесь. Vera: "еще некошеные луга".
И опять: зачем слитно? Предлагалось так: "давно НЕ ЧИЩЕНАЯ обувь".

Comment: Вы приводите формальное правило, которое охватывает большую часть написаний и в целом соответствует семантике и грамматике слов. Но иногда семантика и грамматика в это правило не укладываются, выходят на первое место. Не стоит считать такие случаи проявлением неграмотности авторов или корректоров, пропустивших текст.

Comment: Слава, что вы будете делать с "давно не чищеной обувью"? Получился какой-то гибрид из прилагательного и причастия. Если это причастие, то нужно писать НН. Если это прилагательное, но нужно писать НЕ слитно.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно Грамоте, нужно две н.

Но в данном словосочетании, несмотря на пояснительное слово, все же  выступает значение качества: какая рыба - вяленая, а не что сделанная. В сомнительных случаях нужно подобрать не просто зависимые слова, а пояснительные слова, придающие временной признак. Например: "вяленная рыбаками рыба" или "рыба, вяленная рыбаками".

Comment: @Серж, а про жарен(н)ую рыбу можете то же самое сказать?

Comment: Предлагается разумный компромисс. Пока вы учитесь в школе, то законопослушно пишете "жаренная в сметане рыба". Когда вы окончите школу, станете писателем и будете сочинять романы, то требуйте для себя авторского права на свободное написание подобных выражений. Даже при наличии пояснительного слова качество  будет позволительно обозначать отглагольным прилагательным (Н), а действие причастием (НН), что ни в коей мере не противоречит русской грамматике.

Comment: Интересно, что в 19 веке форма "жаренный" в виде причастия использовалась и без зависимых слов: "Затем более всего в почете жаренная птица ― курица и индейка". "Из опилок вытаскивается кусок мяса, кость, жаренная картофелина". "Кукуруза ― варенная в соленой воде и жаренная".

Comment: >> Когда вы окончите школу, станете писателем и будете сочинять романы, то требуйте для себя авторского права на свободное написание подобных выражений.

Ага, кажется, это называется "выверенный аграмматизм, длинное свободное дыхание фразы". У кого же я это видел... у Веллера, во! Но боюсь, что здесь все же не тот случай. )))

Comment: Уважаемый Niemand, давайте назовем это явление "выверенный аформатизм".

Answer (score 0):

*Давно не чищенная рыба* пишется с *нн*, так как есть зависимое слово *давно*, следовательно *чищенная* - это причастие, и раздельно.