# Сколько н в слове не крепленное?

Tags: удвоенные-буквы

Вино не крепленное спиртом. Сколько Н?

Answer (score 2):

Две. Причастие имеет зависимое слово СПИРТОМ, поэтому НН.

И запятая нужна, так как причастный оборот стоит после определяемого слова.

***Вино, не креплённое спиртом.***

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы всё правильно,  существует **две формы**; креплёное вино  — это прилагательное, а вино, крепленное спиртом, водкой, самогоном — причастие, две буквы НН пишутся при наличии зависимого слова.

В словаре есть слово "креплёный": КРЕПЛЁНЫЙ,  Содержащий спиртовые добавки (о вине). К-ое виноградное вино. Но почему-то нет глагола "крепить" со значением "повышать  крепость вина". В текстах причастие "крепленный" по отношению к вину используется редко, популярностью не пользуется.

Впрочем, всё это не должно отменять основное правило о влиянии зависимых слов на выбор двух НН.

Comment: Здесь была интересная дискуссия: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46010/Сколько-н-в-слове-не-крепленное

Comment: Тема очень сложная, поэтому предлагается ее решать формально: увидел зависимое слово - значит, это причастие, пишутся две буквы НН . Не учитывать зависимые слова вовсе - это тоже неверное решение, если мы хотим различать причастия и прилагательные по постоянному качеству или процессуальному признаку. Правильно было бы учитывать  характер зависимого слова,  а именно значение времени, которое оно придает действию (ещё, пока,  вчера и т.д).   А крепленное спиртом вино - это только разновидность качества, и две буквы НН в нем - формальное решение.

Comment: Кстати, на формальную запись уже точно выработался рефлекс: так и хочется написать две буквы НН, если видишь зависимое слово. Вот только не стоит тратить время на объяснение того, что перед нами причастие, это скорее всего не так.